# beautifulsoup export to csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm capturing data from fields and store it as

```
data.append(newdata)
```

Each complete record is then stored as:

```
list_of_rows.append(data)
```

I'm then trying to save to a csv

```
data_mod = [[item] for item in list_of_rows]

with open("./hotels.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in data_mod:
        writer.writerow(row)
outfile.close()
```

But when I load it into the csv everything gets saved into the first field.  How do I break it down correctly?

**EDIT**

Each row looks like

`[[u'Staybridge Suites London - Vauxhall', '\nTushar K\n', '\nIlford\n', 0, u'2 reviews', '5 of 5 stars', '29 September 2016', u'\nHome comes at staybridge........it nice with stay bridge.....awesome ambiance, kitchen, rooms, break fast area.............\nEverything is at place.....\nTalking about people of stay bridge... they all are very much cooperative, kind, best service people I have ever saw, meet...... its absolutely fantastic with stay bridge..........love u guysss.....\n']]`

Comment: Why are you opening the file in binary mode? Unrelated but you could just use `writer.writerows(data_mod)`

Comment: I'm not aware I am opening in binary - what should the line be?  `writer.writerows(data_mod)` still doesn't allow me to load into csv in separate fields; everything comes into the first column

Comment: `"wb"` b-> binary mode, you just need `w`. What does `data_mod` look like?

Comment: added an example output row

Comment: A list inside a list?

Comment: Yes, it's the first time I've looked at it like that and it shouldn't be; I'm trying to see why

Comment: because you are wrapping it in a list, see the answer below.

Comment: How do you have an integer in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap the rows in lists, you already have a list of lists. You also need to strip the newlines or each line will get it's own line as opposed to writing all in one row and encode to utf-8:

```
with open("./hotels.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows([s.strip().encode("utf-8") if isinstance(s, unicode) else s
                     for s in row] for row in list_of_rows)
```

Comment: I've just tried this and I'm getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)` when writing the csv file.

Comment: The edit should work, where are you getting this data from? You have unicode, str and integers all mixed up together.

Comment: I'm scraping it off a webpage - tripadviser

Comment: I cannot see how you could possibly get all the different types, they should all be unicode strings unless you are changing them manually. bs4 gives you unicode so you are definitely doing something to it.

Comment: No worries, I would leave everything as unicode then do the encode before you write.

Comment: Yes, that's what I changed it back to